# How to display sorted map from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am making audio streaming app. I have already made a list of albums with songs attached to each album. I can sort these albums by 'order by' function, but I don't know how to sort the song array. In firebase I've made one main collection called Album and inside of this collection I've made few string files, and one them is map called song which consists of another few string files. And my problem is that I can't sort the songs in swiftui project.

This is audio data code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore
import Firebase


class OurData: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published public var albums = [Album]()
 
    func loadAlbums() {
        Firestore.firestore().collection("Album").order(by: "songs", descending: true)
        Firestore.firestore().collection("Album").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if error == nil {
                for document in snapshot!.documents{
                    let name = document.data()["name"] as? String ?? "error"
                    let image = document.data()["image"] as? String ?? "1"
                    let songs = document.data()["songs"] as? [String : [String : Any]]
                    
                    var songsArray = [Song]()
                    if let songs = songs{
                        for song in songs {
                            let songName = song.value["name"] as? String ?? "error"
                            let songTime = song.value["time"] as? String ?? "error"
                            let artistName = song.value["artistName"] as? String ?? "error"
                            let songFile = song.value["file"] as? String ?? "error"
                            
                            songsArray.append(Song(songName: songName, image: image, time: songTime, artist: artistName, file: songFile))
                        }
                    }
                    self.albums.append(Album(albumName: name, image: image, song: songsArray))
                }
            }else{
                print(error!)
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's audio player code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Album : Hashable {
    var ID = UUID()
    var albumName : String
    var image : String
    var song : [Song]
}

struct Song: Hashable {
    var ID = UUID()
    var songName : String
    var image : String
    var time : String
    var artist : String
    var file : String
}


struct PodcastView : View {
    
    @ObservedObject var data: OurData
    
    @State private var currentAlbum : Album?
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack{
                ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                    LazyHStack{
                        ForEach(self.data.albums, id: \.self, content: {
                            album in
                            AlbumView(album: album).onTapGesture {
                                self.currentAlbum = album
                            }
                        })
                    
                    }
                    
                })
                ScrollView{
                    LazyVStack{
                        if self.data.albums.first == nil {
                            EmptyView()
                            
                        }else{
                            ForEach((self.currentAlbum?.song ?? self.data.albums.first?.song) ?? [Song(songName: "", image: "", time: "", artist: "", file: "")],
                        id: \.self,
                        content: {
                        song in
                            SongCell(album: currentAlbum ?? self.data.albums.first!, song: song)
                            
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Podcasty")
            .foregroundColor(.black)
        }
    }
}


struct AlbumView : View{
    
    var album : Album
    
    var body: some View{
        ZStack (alignment: .bottom, content: {
            Image(album.image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            ZStack{
                Blur(style: .extraLight)
                Text(album.albumName)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }.frame(height: 60, alignment: .center)
        }).frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
        .cornerRadius(15.0)
        .shadow(radius: 10)
        .padding(15)
        
    }
}

struct SongCell : View {
    
    @State var showPlayer = false
    
    var album : Album
    var song : Song
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showPlayer.toggle()
        }){
            HStack{
                Image(song.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .padding()
                VStack{
                    Text(song.songName)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .font(.system(size: 18))
                    Text(song.artist)
                        .font(.system(size: 16))
                }
                Spacer()
                Text(song.time)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                
            }.frame(width: 380, height: 120, alignment: .trailing)
            .background(
                ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .fill(Color.white)
                        .shadow(color: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8039215803, green: 0.8039215803, blue: 0.8039215803, alpha: 1)), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 5)
                })
            .padding(10)
        }.sheet(isPresented: $showPlayer, content: {
            PodcastPlayerView(album: album, song: song)
        })
        
    }
}
```

This is link to screenshot of my Firebase album and song data:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kosciolfiladelfia-6b832.appspot.com/o/zdj%2FZrzut%20ekranu%20(130).png?alt=media&token=78b51b60-62e9-4935-95f9-18e8a1dc6610

Comment: You need to add the definition of your `Song` and `Album` type to your question. It looks to me like you have an array of Album structs, and each Album Struct contains an array of Song structs. It would be fairly simple to use a map statement to rebuild the Albums array to contain songs sorted in a particular order, but I can't guide you on how to do that without seeing your data structures.

Comment: ok so what actually you want me to send, the struct of data from Firebase?

Comment: Add your Swift `Song` and `Album` structs to your question.

Comment: Sorry for asking again but i am new at it, and i am still not sure what do you want from me. I mean i've added almost everything to my question. Don't be mad at me but seriously i don't know what are you asking for, i thought that structs of album and song are attached to an audio player code :/

Comment: You can get this from the Firebase console. Basically, how your data is organized.

Comment: Anyone want to try? After updating my question